# splice function only works once for me

Tags: javascript

```
function goBack(){
    folders = [];
    filesList = {};
    document.getElementById("files").innerHTML = "";
    console.log(currentFolder);
    var currentFolderN = currentFolder.split("\\");
    currentFolderN.pop();
    console.log(currentFolderN);
    currentFolder = "";
    for(var a = 0;a<currentFolderN.length;a++){
        currentFolder = currentFolder + currentFolderN[a] + "\\";
    }
    eel.getFolders(currentFolder);
    eel.getData(currentFolder);
}
```

I made this function with the pop function in it. But it only works once, and does not work anymore after I run it. I tried to do `currentFolderN.splice(-1,1);` but did the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "only works once"? Are you firing `goBack` multiple times?

Comment: I have a button which runs this function, and it splits a string (which is a path to a folder) and I want to remove the last item from it, but it only does it once, even if I spam my button.

Comment: What makes you think it would remove it more than once?

Comment: I don't know a lot about javascript I am new with it.

Comment: Please may you update the example to be a [mre] so that we can understand what's going on?

Comment: what do I have to show more?

Comment: What is “currentFolder”? What is the expected output?

Comment: There's an idea called "idempotence" that's worth reading about. The overly simplified version is "don't write functions that have side-effects". This is very related to another nugget of wisdom (language independent) that says "don't use globals".  More advice: use small, well-tested libraries, like Node->path. Write small functions with small requirements, testing each as you go.  Finally, SO advice: write your question like this: "here's the result I'm going for, here's (all of the relevant and only the relevant) input conditions and code, here's what I tried"

Comment: currentFolder is a string variable is a path to a folder.

Comment: it's value is "d:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop\\CosmosOffline\\test"